# Active enumeration script problems

Tags: bash, shell, enumeration

I am trying to create a script that has functions of active enumeration:1.  Enumerate all machines on the network using ICMP protocol (considering TTL and Packet Size)
2.  Enumerate all machines on the network using ARP protocol
3.  Enumerate and map machines on the network based on ICMP and ARP
4.  Enumerate at least 5 well-known ports on each machine and map them to the result of Task 2.c
5.  Keep bandwidth below the threshold
6.  Produce human-readable/grepable output
7.  Perform DNS reconnaissance
8.  Perform Analysis of how much traffic has been generated by the script.
9.  Perform Passive Enumeration (Optional)
so far my script is this

```
echo Enter Ip address with port and range '(for nmap)'
read ipad

echo Enter 2 ip addresses 'for arp-scan', Ip2 enter 0 'if' no range
read ip1
read ip2
# enumerating machines on the network using ARP protocol

nmap -sP -PI $ipad

# enumerating 5 ports
echo "Enumerated ports "
: > task.file
nmap -sn $ipad -oG - | grep Up | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | >> task.file

nmap -iL task.file
# enumerating using ARP

echo arp scan":"
if [ $ip2 == 0 ]; then
        arp-scan $ip1
else
        arp-scan $ip1-$ip2
fi
```

For some reason `nmap -sn $ipad -oG - | grep Up | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | >> task.file` doesn't work in the script but when used as a command line it works perfectly, where did I go wrong

Comment: `| >>` - remove the `|`

Comment: Oh shit, how did I miss that, I think it will work just need to check it